# Display data in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, datagrid

I am working with C# in Visual Studio Community 2013.  I have been trying to display data in a DataGrid that I have set up in a Window in my application.  I've been finding various web pages including 1 or 2 from stackoverflow that are supposed to show ways of inserting and displaying the data, but every time I try one of these approaches, it doesn’t work for me.

Most of the time it seems like the code in these pages is from a previous or different version of Visual Studio and it just won’t work with Visual Studio Community 2013.  I say that because I keep getting error messages in VS 2013 telling me the code isn’t correct in one way or another.  This is when I’ve copied what’s in the corresponding web page exactly.  Also, I’ve usually spent time looking into the errors without finding a way of resolving them.

I just want to be able to insert data into the DataGrid so that I can see it when I look at the app.

Please can someone show me how this needs to be done, or point me in the direction of a website/page that will show me how to get this working?  This is obviously in Visual Studio Community 2013.  I realise that I need to use data binding, but so far I haven’t found a way of doing that that actually works in my code.

I could paste the code I have so far up here, but there’s a lot of it and it would take up a lot of space.  I will therefore hold off from doing that until someone actually asks for it.

At this stage I have the database data set up in class instances, which store the data that I want to display.  The data is all just bits of text or numeric values.  The instances are stored in a class that’s like a CollectionBase List, so that I can get individual instances from the list as I need them.  My aim is to be able to display all of the instances, or just some of the instances from the list, dependent on how the user interacts with the application.  However, at this stage I just want to be able to display something, and so far that hasn’t been possible.

I also have the DataGrid set up with all the required headers for the various columns, plus various settings that I found were needed from looking on line.  These can obviously be changed as and when I get some guidance on how to sort this out.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There have been a number of different ways of doing it that I've found and the errors, or problems have been different with each one.

Comment: With the last one I tried, which was dated 2013, I was being shown to use:

Comment: ObserverableCollection collection = new ObservableCollection() - which looked like it was supposed to store the data I wanted to display.

Comment: But when I set the code up, as shown in the web page,  ObserverableCollection was causing errors - error message was: Using the generic type 'System.Collections,ObjectModel.ObserverableCollection<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: I didn't really understand the error message, but looked it up online.  I then found other examples where the '<>' had a list like object in it.  I then tried putting my CollectionBase List (as discussed above) between the <>.  That reduced the errors, but it still wouldn't work.  I was getting 'List' is a field but is used like a 'type'

Comment: I hope I'm sort of close with ObserverableCollection collection = new ObservableCollection(), but I need to know what else I have to do to get it all working.